# How to inspect calender using Selenium web driver in reach js?

Tags: java, testing, automation

Calender logo/icon is visible but not able to inspect. Trying to do automation testing.

Calender logo is visible but not able to inspect it. Trying to do automation testing. Not able to inspect it . trying to do selenium automation testing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.